# Terrafrom resource creation condition, error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

can someone help me to resolve the issue, with creation of resource

> **Goal:**    Creation of resource with condition
>
> **Error:**   No error
>
> **Problem:** Resource is creating even if parent resource is disabled
>
> **Expecting**:

`If transit gateway is disabled, current resource should not be created`

`if transit gateway is enabled, current resource should be created`

```
resource "aws_ec2_tag" "tgw_rtbl" {
   depends_on                      = [ aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw ] 
   resource_id                     = var.create_tgw_gateway ? aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw[0].association_default_route_table_id : ""
   key                             = each.key
   value                           = each.value
   lifecycle { 
       create_before_destroy       = true
       ignore_changes              = [ resource_id ] 
   }
   for_each  = { 
       "Name"  : local.tag_default_rtbl
       "Zone"  : upper(var.region)
   }
}
```

As requested here is the Transit Gateway resource

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway" "tgw" {
   count                           = var.create_tgw_gateway && length(var.region) > 0 ? 1 : 0
   description                     = var.tgw_descriptions

   amazon_side_asn                 = var.amazon_asn_supporting
   dns_support                     = var.enable_dns_supporting
   vpn_ecmp_support                = var.enable_vpn_supporting
   default_route_table_association = var.default_rtb_association 
   default_route_table_propagation = var.default_rtb_propagation
   auto_accept_shared_attachments  = var.accept_attachments
 

   lifecycle { 
       create_before_destroy = true
       ignore_changes        = [ tags ] 
   }

  
   tags = merge(
     {
         "Name"  = join(" | ", [
             format("%s | ${var.tgw_gateway_tag} · %s", var.identity_tags, var.master_cidrblock_ipvf),
             upper(var.region)
         ])
         "Tier"  = title("transit gateway")
         "Cidr"  = var.master_cidrblock_ipvf
     }
   )
}
```

Comment: Can you paste here the TF code snippet for `tgw` as well?

Comment: Yeah. Especially we need to understand what exactly is meant by `disabled/enabled` for tgw

Comment: Sure, I will add, sorry I thought it is not necessary

Comment: Done, I've completed the question

Comment: You should use `count                           = var.create_tgw_gateway && length(var.region) > 0 ? 1 : 0` also in `aws_ec2_tag.tgw_rtbl`.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I know with `count` I can do a condition, but as you may see my purpose is to create a condition, with `for_each`, as `for_each` gives me an opportunity to manage multiple tags, if I would do only one `name` tag, than for sure I would use `count`. Just FYI count and for_each could not be used together.